# SIGIO only notifies last thread in threadpool

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, threadpool

I would like to write a program that, upon `SIGIO`, signals all of the threads in my threadpool. I have written the following code, but it appears that a socket can only be owned by a single thread at a time, and thus will only notify the last thread in my thread pool of an event. Is there some way I can get my desired behaviour without using a dedicated signal-capturing thread and without having the main process be interrupted?

```
void sigFunc(int signo){
    printf("SIGNAL %li!\n", gettid());
    return;
}

static void* poolFunc(){
    printf("Pool func... %li\n", gettid());

    fcntl(lsocket, F_SETOWN, gettid());

    for(;;)
        sleep(1);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned char val;
    int lsocket;
    pthread_t pool[4];

    lsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Omitted 15 lines of setting up lsocket, this part is boring

    fcntl(lsocket, F_SETFL, fcntl(lsocket, F_GETFL) | O_ASYNC);

    signal(SIGIO, sigFunc);

    for(val=0; val < 4; val++){
        if(pthread_create(&pool[val], NULL, poolFunc, NULL) != 0){
            printf("Creation of thread pool failed!\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(pthread_detach(pool[val]) != 0){
            printf("Failed to detach thread in pool...?\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    printf("Starting main loop...\n");

    for(;;)
        sleep(1);
}
```

Output:

> $ ./program
> Pool func... 17580
> Pool func... 17582
> Pool func... 17581
> Pool func... 17583
> Pool func... 17584
> Starting main loop...
> SIGNAL 17584!
> SIGNAL 17584!
> SIGNAL 17584!
> SIGNAL 17584!
> SIGNAL 17584!
> ^C
>
> $ ./program
> Pool func... 17621
> Pool func... 17620
> Pool func... 17623
> Pool func... 17624
> Pool func... 17622
> Starting main loop...
> SIGNAL 17622!
> SIGNAL 17622!
> SIGNAL 17622!
> SIGNAL 17622!
> SIGNAL 17622!
> ^C

Comment: `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.  It cannot be safely used in a signal handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signal disposition is on process level.

This means only one thread of a process will receive a signal being sent to the process.

In other words: From outside the process *only one* of the process' threads can be signalled.

To signal *all* threads within a process `pthread_kill()` can be used by each of the process' *own* threads. To do so the process needs to keep track of all its existing (created and still alive) threads.

Comment: Using this method, I will need to signal each thread individually, correct? I can't just signal them all simultaneously?

Comment: @ChatTor: Yes, you cannot. At least not using signals.

Comment: Is there a way I can do so without using signals?

Comment: @ChatTor: The only possibility I see you already mentioned in your question, that is to have a dedicated thread catching the relevant signal(s) and make this thread call `pthread_kill()` on each of the process' other threads. If you exclude the main thread from being signalled it would not get interrupted.

Comment: Alright. Cool. Like I said in the question, I'd like to avoid that, but it seems like it's the only real possibility at this point. Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions